# How to create a basic 4 area template that fits the screen (w/o scrolling or explicit height setting of middle areas) in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I (or what is the best way) in Bootstrap 4 make a (basic?) layout template that looks like the image at the bottom?

Requirements:

1. **Note that I want the divs/containers for content1 and content2 to fill up the space between navbar and footer to fit any users browser window exactly** and to not exceed in height and cause a scrollbar to be created on the entire page.
2. The footer should always remain below content1 and content2 and always visible on the user's page at the bottom like a sticky footer.
3. Any new containers/divs created within content2 (or content1) should autofit the entire area of content2 (or content1).
4. **I want to avoid setting an explicit height on content1 and content2, unless it is a class name, but I don't want specific things like 700px to be set as a height because again, I want it to fit any users display, and 700px may be just right for some, but leave a lot of white space for others between content1 and content2 and the footer.**
5. Navbar and Footer areas can have an explicit height set, and the margins/padding of content1 and content2 can be explicitly set too if necessary. I just want to avoid explicitly setting the height of content1 and content2.

All samples I have seen make a 'scrollable' page where content can extend beyond the user's browser height and users can scroll up and down the page to see content, whereas in my case I want the 4 regions in the image below to fit my screen exactly so there is no scrolling. If there is scrolling due to overflow of text content in content1, then overflow:auto should allow for scrolling of content1 or content2 and not for the entire page.

[image]

If what I am asking for is not possible, please provide the best alternative with a sample that would be ideal to accomplish what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy work with **Bootstrap@4** or using `flex-box` `CSS`. Check the snippet using **Bootstrap@4**.

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .main-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.header-wrapper{
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-wrapper{
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.body-wrapper{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-1{
  background-color: #2DC050;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-2{
  background-color: #1FA325;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .content-1,
  .content-2{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="main-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="header-wrapper fixed-top d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed header. I will be alwase visible on top. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
  <div class="body-wrapper d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-1 d-flex flex-column text-center">
        <h1>I'm content One. My position is left. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-2 d-flex flex-column">
        <h1>I'm content Two. My position is right. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper fixed-bottom d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed footer. I will be alwase visible on bottom. I'm fixed height.
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Header and Footer always `fixed`.
2. Content 1 and Content 2 will be `scroll-able` if browser `min-width`
   is `992px`.
3. Entire page will be `scroll-able` if browser `max-width` is `991px`.

**Edit for [Ronaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971888/rolando) comments**. Answer is yes it's possible. Check the bottom snippet.

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.header-wrapper{
  background-color: #009688;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-wrapper{
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.body-wrapper{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .body-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.content-1{
  background-color: #2DC050;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-2{
  background-color: #1FA325;
  color: white;
  min-height: 700px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .content-1{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
.content-2-1{
  background-color: #0D420F;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="header-wrapper fixed-top d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed header. I will be alwase visible on top. I'm fixed height.
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="body-wrapper d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-1 d-flex flex-column text-center">
        <h1>I'm content One. My position is left. I'm alwase fit with any browser window except header and footer height. Also I'm scrollable if content isn't fit.</h1>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row pl-0 pr-0">
      <div class="content-2 d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="content-2-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
          I'm Content 2 child element. My parent content-2 background color name is Forest Green. My background color is Myrtle. My width and height is 100%. I follow my parent height.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-wrapper fixed-bottom d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    I'm fixed footer. I will be alwase visible on bottom. I'm fixed height.
</div>
```

1. New snippet are `html` structure is changed.
2. Remove `page scroll` from `.main-wrapper` `class` and add to
   `body-wrapper` `class`.
3. If need to `child` box `100%` `width` and `height` then `parent`
   should be `display: flex;` `flex-direction: row;` and `child` box
   should be `width: 100%; // width can be changed if it multiple`child`box.` Check the `.content-2` and `.content-2-1` `CSS` code.

> Note: All snippet check in full page view and resize the browser window to check mobile responsive.

Comment: With this implementation, is it possible to put a div inside of the green area  and say "width:100%;height:100%" and have it take up all the green space without 'overflowing'? Or is there an alternate way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Rolando Yes, it's possible. Check the new snippet.